# Inserting a column value with null in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, null

I want to customize the value inserted in the column in the controller and i want to insert a null value in it. In this way :

```
@users.to = null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
@user.to = nil
```

You may have to run a migration to ensure the column allows NULL values:

```
change_column :users, :to, :string, :null => true
```